# Accessing a field of the class from a different thread

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class that contains a vector of Facebook friends data:

```
std::vector<FBFriend> m_friends
```

The FB is a very simple struct:

```
struct FBFriend
{
    std::string ID;
    std::string photoPath;
    std::string name;
    bool installed;
    int score;
};
```

When I download the data from FB (in an async thread), I iterate over the m_friends field, to assign the corresponding picture, but I get bad access error.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us how you access m_friends?

Comment: As a rule, access to elements in a vector from more than one thread needs to be protected by some sort of lock, to prevent one thread from, for example, allocating a new data buffer, while another thread is using the elements in the "current" buffer which is now free memory.

Comment: Please show some code for how you populate the vector and also how you are accessing m_friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing a variable from multiple threads the reads and writes must be synchronized to avoid a *data race*.

Here's a simple example of how you can synchronize access using `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard`:

```
std::mutex m;
std::vector<FBFriend> v;

// Add two FBFriend to vector.
v.push_back({"user1", "/photos/steve", "Steve", true, 0});
v.push_back({"user2", "/photos/laura", "Laura", true, 0});

// Change element in vector from a different thread.
auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m); // Aquire lock before writing.
    v[0].photoPath = "/images/steve";
});

f.wait(); // Wait for task to finish.

std::cout << v[0].photoPath << std::endl;
std::cout << v[1].photoPath << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
/images/steve
/photos/laura
```